# Mirroring an Image in Java

Tags: java, image, swing

**Background info:** I've made a program that uploads an image using JFileChooser and fills in the space of the JFrame. I then apply filters via buttons. Currently 3 of my 4 filters work, or all except my mirror one. It randomly (or I guess not so randomly as there's always a reason, I just don't know what I did) worked a couple times.

**My Question:** I've attempted following a tutorial but had to make slight changes so that I can save it to a new file via a button that has a JFile Chooser. Currently when I save it, it does not mirror however my other filters do what there supposed to with the same slight changes. What is wrong with my mirror logic? Any help is appreciated!

**My code:**

***Global Variables:***

```
// Save Button
private final JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save Files");
private File selFile1;
private File output = new File("Output.png");
private File selFile2;
private String path1;
```

***Upload file:***

```
// Browse Files Button ActionListener
BrowseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser getFile = new JFileChooser();
        getFile.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        // Filter files
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter1 = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg", "png");
        getFile.addChoosableFileFilter(filter1);
        int res = getFile.showSaveDialog(null);
        if(res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            selFile1 = getFile.getSelectedFile();
            path1 = selFile1.getAbsolutePath();
            label.setIcon(resize(path1));
            System.out.println("1st selFile1 = " + selFile1);
            try {
                getImg = ImageIO.read(selFile1);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            } // End try-catch
            
        } // End if
    } // End actionPerformer
}); // End ActionListener
}); // End ActionListener
```

***Save File:***

```
    // Save Files Button ActionListener
    saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser getFile = new JFileChooser();
            getFile.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            // Filter files
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter1 = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg",
                    "png");
            getFile.addChoosableFileFilter(filter1);
            int res = getFile.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                selFile2 = getFile.getSelectedFile();
                path1 = selFile2.getAbsolutePath();
                label.setIcon(resize(path1));
                System.out.println("1st selFile1 = " + selFile2);                    
                try {
                   
                    ImageIO.write(getImg, "png", selFile2);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                } // End try-catch
                
            } // End if
        } // End actionPerformer
    }); // End ActionListener
```

***grayScale method that works:***

```
grayScale.setMnemonic('G'); //Hot key
        // ActionListener for grayscale button
        grayScale.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   
            File f = selFile1;

            // Read image
            try{
                getImg = ImageIO.read(f);
            } catch(IOException ef){
                System.out.println(ef);
            } // End try-catch

            // Get image width and height
            int width = getImg.getWidth();
            int height = getImg.getHeight();

            // Convert to grayscale
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
                for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                    int p = getImg.getRGB(x,y);

                    int a = (p>>24)&0xff;
                    int r = (p>>16)&0xff;
                    int g = (p>>8)&0xff;
                    int b = p&0xff;

                    // Calculate average
                    int avg = (r+g+b)/3;

                    // Replace RGB value with avg
                    p = (a<<24) | (avg<<16) | (avg<<8) | avg;

                    getImg.setRGB(x, y, p);
                }
            } // End for
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(comboBoxPanel, "Gray Scale Filter has been applied. Save to view!");
            // Write image
            try {
                f = output;
                ImageIO.write(getImg, "png", f);
            } catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            } // End try-catch
            
            } // End actionPerformed
        }); //End ActionListener
```

***Mirror method that doesn't work:***

```
mirrored.setMnemonic('M'); // Hot Key
        // ActionListener for mirror button
        mirrored.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            File f = selFile1;
            BufferedImage res = null;
            
            try{
                getImg = ImageIO.read(f);
                res = ImageIO.read(f);
            } catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            } // End try-catch
            // Get source image dimension
            int width = getImg.getWidth();
            int height = getImg.getHeight();
            //BufferedImage for mirror image
            res = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            //create mirror image pixel by pixel
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
                for(int lx = 0, rx = width - 1; lx < width; lx++, rx--){
                // lx starts from the left side of the image
                // rx starts from the right side of the image
                // Get source pixel value
                int p = getImg.getRGB(lx, y);
                // Set mirror image pixel value - both left and right
                res.setRGB(rx, y, p);
                }
            } // End for
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(comboBoxPanel, "Mirrored Filter has been applied. Save to view!");
            // Write image
            try{
              f = output;
              ImageIO.write(res, "png", f);
            } catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            } // End try-catch
        } // End actionPerformed 
        }); // End actionListener
```

***GUI (For Reference):***

[image: My GUI]

Comment: When you process a line from one side to another you swap every pixel _twice_  resulting in an unaltered picture.

Comment: When asking a question post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. Your issue is with the "mirror" part, so the gray scale logic is irrelevant to the question. Also the file chooser is irrelevant. Just hardcode the file name for test purposes.

Comment: @camickr My apologizes, I added the grayScale logic as an example to show a working method thinking it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, speculation, you start out by doing...

```
File f = selFile1;
BufferedImage res = null;

try {
    getImg = ImageIO.read(f);
    res = ImageIO.read(f);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
} // End try-catch
```

And you end by doing this...

```
// Write image
try {
    f = output;
    ImageIO.write(res, "png", f);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
} // End try-catch
```

But, `getImg` is still pointing to the source (unmodified) image.  If you're using this to display the result to the user, then you're displaying the wrong image.  Based on you other "filter" operations, you're modifying the `getImg` directly.

Now, having said that, your code is, questionable, at best.

Let me explain...

```
File f = selFile1;
BufferedImage res = null;

try {
    getImg = ImageIO.read(f);
    res = ImageIO.read(f);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
} // End try-catch
```

How do you know `selFile1` is not `null` or that it points to a valid `File`?  You've done no checking here.  Also, what's the point of reading the file twice, especially when you do `res = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);` immediately after it?

This raises another question, what happens if the image loading fails?  You carry on trying to use the `getImg` reference anyway, which may contain "dirty" data or worse, be `null`.

Instead, I might do something more like...

```
if (selFile1 == null) {
    // Show error message
    // Use JOptionPane to show message to user
    return;
}

try {
    BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read(selFile1);
    // Get source image dimension
    int width = sourceImage.getWidth();
    int height = sourceImage.getHeight();
    //BufferedImage for mirror image
    BufferedImage mirroredImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    //create mirror image pixel by pixel
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int lx = 0, rx = width - 1; lx < width; lx++, rx--) {
            // lx starts from the left side of the image
            // rx starts from the right side of the image
            // Get source pixel value
            int p = sourceImage.getRGB(lx, y);
            // Set mirror image pixel value - both left and right
            mirroredImage.setRGB(rx, y, p);
        }
    } // End for
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(comboBoxPanel, "Mirrored Filter has been applied. Save to view!");
    // Write image
    ImageIO.write(mirroredImage, "png", selFile1);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    // Use JOptionPane to show message to user
} // End try-catch
```

Now you could also isolate the write within a inner `try-catch`, but the point is try and do some preemptive checking to prevent known issues from crashing your code.

Oh, and you might find...

```
BufferedImage mirrored = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = mirrored.createGraphics();
g2d.scale(-1, 1);
g2d.translate(-source.getWidth(), 0);
g2d.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

And much simpler way to mirror an image

Comment: Writing out to selFile1 will mirror the original image and not the one getting saved. In my other filter method, grayScale, I had declared f = selFile1, then when I go to write it out I make f = output. Output is a global file ("Output.png") and then the saved copy is the one with the applied filter and not vice versa. At least that's my understanding of it. What am I missing here? I still cannot get it to apply to the saved copy.

Comment: This is the problem with out of context code, it’s difficult to fully understand what’s going on

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scale()` method of the `Graphics2D` object to do this for you:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class MirrorImage extends JPanel
{
    public MirrorImage()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( new File("dukewavered.gif") );

            JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( image ) );
            add(label);

            BufferedImage mirrorImage = createMirror( image );
            JLabel mirror = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( mirrorImage ) );
            add(mirror);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public BufferedImage createMirror(Image image)
    {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.translate(bi.getWidth(), 0);
        g2d.scale(-1, 1);
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        g2d.dispose();

        return bi;
     }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mirror Image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new MirrorImage());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```